# How can I set all array elements in an element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array

```
    let array = [1, 2, 3];
```

I want all elements of this array to set on an element in HTML for example

```
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

I want the output to be 1 , 2 , 3

Last number I dont want to have comma

I tried something

```
       let array = [1,  2, 3]
       for(var i =0; i <=array.length;i++) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array[i] + "' , ";}
```

Thanks so much

Comment: so set the text with toString or join

Comment: Setting `.innerHTML = something` will overwrite the output with each iteration; use `+=` instead. `i <=array.length` is a classic off-by-one error. It’s `i < array.length`. Consider using [`Array` iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods instead, at least in general. In this case, a simple `document.getElementById("demo").textContent = array.join(", ");` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop, use toArray or join.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];

document.getElementById("demo").textContent = array.toString();

document.getElementById("demo2").textContent = array.join(', ');
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<p id="demo2"></p>
```

If you want to loop you need to check the index and add the comma

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];

let out = '';

for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
   const comma = i == 0 ? '' : ', ';
   out += comma + array[i];
}

document.getElementById("demo").textContent = out;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```